# How to have a date that updates that is not today's in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to make a pivot table that shows information that was updated in the last week.  In the list I'm pulling from, someone manually inserts the date as necessary.  I am a novice at VBA, but the idea I have is to have a reference cell that has a date that automatically updates to a week ago from the current date.  Is there a way to do this?  I'm also going to have the same table except for the last month so if this is different then please let me know the coding for this as well.  Thanks in advance for the help!  It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little hard to follow. You mention VBA but then talk about a cell with a reference. Since you didn't post the code you're working with, I will assume you are referring to a cell formula.

You can use this formula in the cell of your choice to get today's date minus 7 days.

```
=Today()-7
```

To back date a month simply change the `7` to `30`.

If you are truly working with VBA, please add the code to your question so we can help you with it.

Comment: that just simplified my problem significantly. I thought vba would be necessary but apparently I was mistaken.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: `=today()-30` is not a month ago, it is 30 days ago.

Comment: As far as I can think of off the top of my head, you'd need to use the following to get one month ago: `=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()-1),DAY(TODAY()))`

Answer (score 0):

As CharlieRB said, the following gives you the date of 7 days ago:

```
=TODAY()-7
```

30 days ago is similarly easy, but one month ago is a tad more complicated. To my knowledge, the following would be the most straightforward way to do it:

```
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()-1),DAY(TODAY()))
```

Also, you may want to hit <kbd>F9</kbd> when in the spreadsheet to make sure the today() functions update.